# Lucee 5.3.8 CFChart URL Disable

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, cfchart

Lucee CFChart type pie from query markup:

```
<cfchart chartheight="600" chartwidth="800" showborder="true" title="Levels">
<cfchartseries query="#layout.querymap[layout.QueryName]#" type="pie" itemcolumn="Title" valuecolumn="Amount" />
</cfchart>
```

creates this HTML:

```
<map id="chart_8" name="chart_8">
<area shape="poly" coords="211,170,225,147,242,126,262,108,284,93,307,80,333,71,359,66,386,64,386,263,386,263" title="84000" alt="" href="#?series=0&category=xxxx&value=84000.0"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="176,278,178,254,182,230,189,208,199,186,374,278,374,278" title="37500" alt="" href="#?series=0&category=xxxx&value=37500.0"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="275,468,254,453,235,436,218,416,204,395,193,372,185,348,180,323,179,297,377,297,377,297" title="80000" alt="" href="#?series=0&category=xxxx&value=80000.0"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="516,471,491,487,465,498,437,505,409,509,380,508,352,503,325,494,299,481,401,310,401,310" title="90000" alt="" href="#?series=0&category=xxxx&value=90000.0"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="610,359,598,388,581,416,561,440,536,461,420,300,420,300" title="50000" alt="" href="#?series=0&category=xxxx&value=50000.0"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="588,168,600,188,610,208,617,229,621,251,623,273,623,296,620,318,614,340,425,281,425,281" title="70000" alt="" href="#?series=0&category=xxxx&value=70000.0"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="412,63,436,65,459,69,482,76,504,86,524,99,543,113,560,130,575,149,412,262,412,262" title="75000" alt="" href="#?series=0&category=xxxx&value=75000.0"/>
</map><img border="0" usemap="#chart_8" src="/lucee/graph.cfm?img=f09a50705458509f66c5f37628f0bdea&type=png">
```

I want the static image alone; no href links, no area tags, no map tags.

An empty url attribute doesn't work; a documentation search was futile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `source` attribute of [`cfchart`](https://docs.lucee.org/reference/tags/chart.html). It will store the `src` attribute of the generated image in the specified variable.

```
<cfchart source="myChartImage" ...>
  <cfchartseries ...>
</cfchart>

<cfdump var="#myChartImage#">
```

Using your example, `myChartImage` would be a string with a value of `/lucee/graph.cfm?img=f09a50705458509f66c5f37628f0bdea&type=png`.

If you want to store the generated chart image as an actual file without calling `/lucee/graph.cfm`, you need to request the URI via `cfhttp` using the `getAsBinary` attribute and retrieve the data as byte array. You can then write it to disk or encode it as base64 or hex etc.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex - thank you! This produces bare img tag I want:

```
<cfchart chartheight="600" chartwidth="800" showborder="true" title="Levels" source="imagesource">
<cfchartseries query="#layout.querymap[layout.QueryName]#" type="pie" itemcolumn="Title" valuecolumn="DonationAmount" />
</cfchart><cfoutput>
<img src="#imagesource#">
</cfoutput>
```